# Quero printar uma dupla fita de DNA no shell do python

Tags: python-3.x, formatação

estou tentando printar uma sequência de nucleotídeos com python da seguinte forma:

```
tatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatata
||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
atatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatat
```

o problema é que quando uso uma sequência maior fica assim:

`tatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatata
||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
atatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatat`

Queria saber se tem como quebrar a linha pra que o resultado saia formatado, de forma que ele se amolde de acordo com o tamanho da janela dessa forma:

[image: ex janela lista]
[image: ex janela lista 2]

ps.: o código que eu usei foi:

```
>>> e = 'ta'*200
>>> f = 'at'*200
>>> g = '|'*400
>>> print('{}\n{}\n{}\n{}'.format(e,g,g,f))
```

Comment: Eu estou convicto que a única forma mesmo é separar em vários bocados. Se nao for, tem que esclarecer qual éo resultado que espera.

Comment: Obrigado ter dado mais informacoes. Eu nao editei a minha resposta porque mesmo com a informacao adicional nao tenho outra solucao. Pode esperar por outras respsotas

Comment: eu estava pesquisando como retornar o tamanho e largura da janela usando o módulo 'os', só que só funciona quando o programa está aberto no cmd, não no shell... obrigado de qualquer forma

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nao há resposta certa para esta pergunta.

O seu `output` aparece formatado dessa forma por causa do tamanho da janela. Se a janela fosse grande o suficiente voce conseguia ver o seu output normalmente.

Contúdo voce pode mostrar o seu output em vários bocados por exemplo:

```
tatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatata
||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
atatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatat

tatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatata
||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
atatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatatat
```

Para fazer isso pode usar esta forma

```
def split_input(string, chunk_size):
    num_chunks = len(string)/chunk_size
    if (len(string) % chunk_size != 0):
        num_chunks += 1
    output = []
    for i in range(0, int(num_chunks)):
        output.append(string[chunk_size * i:chunk_size * (i+1)])
    return output

def printDna(dna1, dna2, tamanho):
    chunks1 = split_input(dna1, tamanho)
    chunks2 = split_input(dna2, tamanho)

    for i in range(0, len(chunks1)):
        print(chunks1[i])
        print('|'*tamanho)
        print(chunks2[i])
        print()

printDna(e, f, 80)
```

[Veja funcionando no ideone](http://ideone.com/o94Mbb)

Comment: Exatamente, o resultado aparece formatado dependendo do tamanho da janela, porém quando, por exemplo, mando printar uma lista qualquer, o resultado se amolda no tamanho da janela. Queria que isso ocorresse com meu resultado

Comment: Onde está  `print('|'*tamanho)` devia estar `print('|'*len(chunks1[i]))`. Eu depois edito, nao sei se a respsota ficou como o OP queria ou nao